# CakePHP plugin models not associating when using Containable

Tags: php, cakephp, containable

I have a CakePHP plugin named `Foo` that has a component, no controller, and several joined models. It's structured like this:

```
/Plugin/Foo/Model/
 -FooModel1.php
 -FooModel2.php
 -FooModel3.php
 -FooModel4.php
```

In order to connect with the standard (non-plugin) code, one of the plugin models is conditionally associated with a standard model called `Bar`. I don't believe this is relevant to the problem, but I want to be thorough.

In `FooController` I make use of `Containable`, several layers deep:

```
$params = array(
  'conditions' => array('Bar.id' => $bar_id),
  'contain' => array(
    'FooModel1' => array(
      'FooModel2' => array(
        'FooModel3' => array('Something', 'FooModel4')
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

This creates an error like:

```
Warning: Model "FooModel2" is not associated with model "FooModel3" [CORE\Cake\Model\Behavior\ContainableBehavior.php, line 339]
```

So in my plugin controller I need to contain plugin models. I've tried prefixing the models with Foo (e.g. `Foo.FooModel1`) but `Containable` thinks I'm trying to get a model named Foo. In the `$hasAndBelongsToMany` array in the plugin models I've tried both `'Model1' => array()` and `'Foo.Model1' => array()`, neither of which work. How do I correctly set up this association?

Side note: when I move the models out of the plugin and into the standard `/Model/` directory everything works fine. The problem seems to come from incorrect associations rather than the logic of the code itself.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Please include your associations in the respective models.

Comment: See dave's comment, Please be clearer on what you try to achive. You could give us the model definitions or table layout. You can see here that http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations using Foo.FooModel1 doesn't help. Besides that, your Model naming is not following conventions http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions. This can get you in trouble if you try to use build-in functionality

Comment: What is the relationship between your FooModels? Your contain array seems to suggest a hasMany/belongsTo relationship between your fooModels but your question mentions HABTM relationships.

Answer (score 3):

When setting up your associations in your models, make sure to prefix plugin models with their plugin name...otherwise cake will generate one on the fly...and not use the file in your plugin...